# Trying to caught an uncaught error from Axios used with React Query (suspense mode true) and NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js, error-handling, axios, react-query

I'm using NextJS, React query (with axios and suspense mode) and I'm trying to catch an error from my API which return 404 en purpose. I succeed to catch it in my error.js file but the same error appear in the console as "uncaught"
[image]

I trying to log and catch this error in my composant where I use the react query too but still I can got it and log it but it still "Uncaught" in the console.

Here's my Home composant
[image]

My route
[image]

And my error.js
[image]

Any idea how to catch this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `error.js` is not catching and properly handling your 404 Error.
Your `GlobalError` component is just logging what was an Error by `useEffect()`.

I guess you'd better adopt `ErrorBoundary` Component to successfully show an error message (in your case, there was an error!)

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    // Define a state variable to track whether is an error or not
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI
 
    return { hasError: true };
  }
  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can use your own error logging service here
    console.log({ error, errorInfo });
  }
  render() {
    // Check if the error is thrown
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>There was an error</h2>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => this.setState({ hasError: false })}
          >
            Try again?
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
 
    // Return children components in case of no error
 
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
 
export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: But isn't NextJS already handle the error Boundary in the error.js file wrapper ? cf : [Error Handling](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling)